# Width of a column in SWT Table

Tags: java, swt

I have a table named **tblMainData** with several columns with a couple of them with width of **0**.

I want to store the all data in the table except those columns with **0** width to a two dimensional array.

How do I check to see if a particular column has **0** width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call [`TableColumn#getWidth()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TableColumn.html#getWidth%28%29):

```
for(int col = 0; col < tblMainData.getColumnCount(); col++)
{
    if(tblMainData.getColumn(col).getWidth() == 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```